# does comcast need to provision my 3rd party modem for me to use it with my 3rd party router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, modem

ive posted another post related to this problem but im asking a very simple q here.

Ive had 3rd party modem and my own router working fine until yesterday. could it be something comcast did on their side?  I think when i bought modem I had to tell comcast the MAC address of the modem... i dont think i had to tell them about my router

now the only thing i can do is hardwire different computers (1 at a time) directly to the ethernet port of the modem. this seems to indicate that comcast doesnt care about whats plugged into that port.

is this true? or does comcast have to provision the modem to allow for a router (thats going to do NAT and DHCP)  to be connected to it?

Comment: Comcast can't see your router or any other device inside your internal network. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I believe you can check http://mydeviceinfo.comcast.net/ for further details regarding 3rd party equipment compatibility issues.

Comment: The problem is on your router's end if you can run machines directly off of the modem.  No, no provisioning for a router.  Comcast can't even see it.

Answer (score 2):

> does comcast need to provision my 3rd party modem for me to use it
> with my 3rd party router

No. Not normally. I use whatever router I wish, and my customers use whatever router they wish. The ISP does not have to provision the modem to use these.

Of course, you do have to configure the router to work with the modem.

There is likely another error. Try resetting both boxes.

Comment: thanks, simple follow on Q here... i had configed  a router to have ip address of 192.168.1.1.    Can i take that router (not connected to anything else) and conect any of its 4 ports to my mac with an ethernet cable and then reach the routers ddwrt interface with a web browser pointed to 192.168.1.1 ?   its not working .       btw...  it took me hours to load ddwrt onto both routers. so im reluctant to reset them before i try other things

Comment: Make sure additional routers have different IP addresses and are configured LAN to LAN.  Otherwise, I think I answered your question.